# UIImage asynchronously is not loading

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, url, asynchronous

I want to get images from url and i was doing this :

```
for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{NSString *MyURL=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://*********/tatoo/%@/%@%d.png" ,@"b",@"b",i+1];


    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^(void) {
        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:MyURL]];

                             UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
                             if (image) {
                                 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                     [tmp addObject:image];
                                 });
                             }
                             });

}

images = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:tmp];
```

Url is valide , but tmp is empty. ANy ideea what's wrong here? Any help will be appreciate !

Comment: Empty when? Show the code

Comment: @Wain empty when i want to add to images array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AsyncImageView to load image without affecting your UI.

Download third party class from 
https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView

```
    AsyncImageView *storeImage = [[AsyncImageView alloc]init];

 //This will load any no logo image first. If url is dead then also it will work
     storeImage.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"no-logo.png"];


  NSString *UrlSTR = @"ANY_IMAGE_URL";
  NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:UrlSTR];
  storeImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
  storeImage.imageURL = imageURL;
```

This will load your Image in background.

Comment: i did what you said but the images from url is not loading .    I used this for adding the images in my array.      [tmp addObject:storeImage.image];  it's ok?

Comment: No the above code will directly add the image into the imageview

Comment: Whats special in adding the image into an array? Anyhow you will be showing it in some imageview right?

Comment: Do you have an ideea why the images are not showed if i dont scroll it down ?

Comment: have you initialized the tmp array in the first logic?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92576/discussion-between-prakash-ravichandran-and-adina-marin).

Answer (score 0):

The asynchronous downloads haven't finished yet, you need to wait for them.

Use an operation queue or a dispatch group to wait until they're all done and then you can use the array.

Note also that you can't guarantee any order of the images in the array because you don't know how long each download will take. Also, it's best not to kick off 60 downloads at the same time...

Answer (score 0):

Have you initialized the tmp before adding the image data?

```
tmp =[NSArray alloc]init];
```

initialize before for loop